# Cannot see debug output when running android emulator

Tags: android, logcat

I've setup android in eclipse according to [this tutoria](http://www.vogella.de/articles/Android/article.html)l. I downloaded the android sdk zip file from [here](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html) and unzipped it to my c drive. Android sdk 2.3.3 api level 10 is installed and I have setup an android virtual device in the android SDK and AVG manager. The settings are as follows

[image]

In Eclipse, when I go to - 'Window -> Show View -> Android -> LogCat', the logcat view opens up. When I start the emulator however, I see absolutely nothing in the logcat window. Any ideas why this might be happening?

==============================================================================

**Update** Unfortunately none of the suggestions are working. I don't see anything
in my devices tab at all. It's empty. See image below.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In that case try to reset adb.

1. Go to the `Devices` view in the DDMS perspective.
2. Click on the `View Menu` button that looks like a down arrow.
3. Select `Reset adb`.

[image: ddms-screenshot]

Of course you'll have to select an application on that device first.

Comment: Yep this did the trick! I followed your steps, restarted Eclipse and it worked a charm. Thanks very much mate ;)

Comment: Fixed after restarting Eclipse, thanks for saving me out of the nightmare!

Answer (score 1):

Try opening the DDMS perspective (in Eclipse, Windows -> Open Perspective -> DDMS), then select the device in the Devices tab (by default in the upper left hand corner). Also make sure the LogCat window is showing too.

I've noticed that sometimes the LogCat window stops updating, but changing the filter (Verbose-Debug-etc) by clicking the round white buttons with letters inside fixes it.

Comment: I tried this but there's nothing showing up in my devices tab.

Answer (score 1):

Probably device is not selected for your logcat.

try 'Window -> Show View -> device and then select the emulator

Comment: Nope, I can't see anything in my devices tab. The emulator launches fine. I don't get it.

Answer (score 1):

May be because your device is not is not selected
In your `Devices` tab (where all the running emulators and devices are shown), select your desired emulator
If your eclipse didn't shows `Devices`, then  `Window -> Show View -> Android -> Devices`

Comment: Good suggestion but nothing shows up in my devices. Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Close the logcat window completely ... kill it ... it's stuck ... then Window-> Show View -> Other -> LogCat

Comment: Tried that but no joy. answer is above